# Objective-C (iOS): Cannot modify a label's text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently writing my first ever iOS app and have ran into an issue I cannot see to figure out on my own or from previous questions. I currently have an app that has two views and it controlled from one ViewController.m file. I would like to change the text in the labels present on the second view when clicking on a percentage button in the first view.

I have been trying to modify the labels by creating Outlets for them as properties. For some reason the code is being executed just not displayed on the screen. I'm wondering if this problem has something to do with the relationships I currently have set up or maybe I am calling the label incorrectly I am not sure. If anyone could help me it would be much appreciated. *(Specifically in the printResults method. In a comment I have added a link to see what the workflow looks like if anyone is interested.)*

**Condensed version of question:**

```
// Label I would like to change the text of (in a second view in the same controller)
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultTitle;

- (void) printResults:(int) percent :(int) weightOnBar :(Weights*) weightObject{
   // How I am trying to modify the text in a method within the viewcontroller.m file
   [self.fortyFivePlateLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test"]];
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Weights.h"

@interface ViewController ()

// Objects represent the text fields
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *weightField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *repsField;

// Objectsrepresent the percentage buttons below the fields
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet id nintyFiveResult;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet id nintyResult;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet id eightyFiveResult;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet id eightyResult;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet id seventyFiveResult;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet id seventyResult;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet id sixtyFiveResult;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet id sixtyResult;

// Weight object used to perform the on bar calculation
@property (strong, nonatomic) Weights *weightObj;

// Labels represent the values on the second view
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fortyFivePlateLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *thirtyFivePlateLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *twentyFivePlateLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tenPlateLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fivePlateLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *twoFivePlateLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.weightField.delegate = self;
    self.repsField.delegate = self;
    self.weightObj = [Weights getInstance];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

/* weightModified: This method is called when the weight field is modified.
   If the reps or weight value entered is equal to zero all of the percentage
   results will be changed to zero. If valid values are passed in both fields
   the percentages of weight will be calculated.
 */
- (IBAction)weightModified:(UITextField *)sender {

    NSLog(@"Weight Input Value: %@", sender.text);
    NSLog(@"Reps Input Value: %@", self.repsField.text);

    if([sender.text isEqualToString:@""] == false && [self.repsField.text isEqualToString:@""] == false){

        NSLog(@"Weight Modified in if statement.");

        // Gather reps and weight value
        int reps = 0;
        int weight = 0;
        weight = [sender.text intValue];
        reps = [self.repsField.text intValue];

        NSLog(@"Weight: %d", weight);
        NSLog(@"Reps: %d", reps);

        int nintyFiveInt = [self oneRepMax :0.95 :reps :weight];
        int nintyInt = [self oneRepMax :0.9 :reps :weight];
        int eightyFiveInt = [self oneRepMax :0.85 :reps :weight];
        int eightyInt = [self oneRepMax :0.8 :reps :weight];
        int seventyFiveInt = [self oneRepMax :0.75 :reps :weight];
        int seventyInt = [self oneRepMax :0.7 :reps :weight];
        int sixtyFiveInt = [self oneRepMax :0.65 :reps :weight];
        int sixtyInt = [self oneRepMax :0.6 :reps :weight];

        NSString *nintyFiveWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"95%%: %d lbs", nintyFiveInt];
        NSString *nintyWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"95%%: %d lbs", nintyInt];
        NSString *eightyFiveWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"95%%: %d lbs", eightyFiveInt];
        NSString *eightyWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"95%%: %d lbs", eightyInt];
        NSString *seventyFiveWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"95%%: %d lbs", seventyFiveInt];
        NSString *seventyWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"95%%: %d lbs", seventyInt];
        NSString *sixtyFiveWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"95%%: %d lbs", sixtyFiveInt];
        NSString *sixtyWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"95%%: %d lbs", sixtyInt];

        [self.nintyFiveResult setTitle:nintyFiveWeight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.nintyResult setTitle:nintyWeight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.eightyFiveResult setTitle:eightyFiveWeight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.eightyResult setTitle:eightyWeight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.seventyFiveResult setTitle:seventyFiveWeight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.seventyResult setTitle:seventyWeight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.sixtyFiveResult setTitle:sixtyFiveWeight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.sixtyResult setTitle:sixtyWeight forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

    else{
        [self.nintyFiveResult setTitle:@"95%%: 0 lbs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.nintyResult setTitle:@"90%%: 0 lbs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.eightyFiveResult setTitle:@"85%%: 0 lbs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.eightyResult setTitle:@"80%%: 0 lbs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.seventyFiveResult setTitle:@"75%%: 0 lbs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.seventyResult setTitle:@"70%%: 0 lbs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.sixtyFiveResult setTitle:@"65%%: 0 lbs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.sixtyResult setTitle:@"60%%: 0 lbs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}

/* repsModified: This method is called when the weight field is modified.
 If the reps or weight value entered is equal to zero all of the percentage
 results will be changed to zero. If valid values are passed in both fields
 the percentages of weight will be calculated.
 */
- (IBAction)repsModified:(UITextField *)sender {

    if([sender.text isEqualToString:@""] == false && [self.repsField.text isEqualToString:@""] == false){

        NSLog(@"Reps Modified in if statement.");

        // Gather reps and weight value
        int reps = 0;
        int weight = 0;
        weight = [self.weightField.text intValue];
        reps = [sender.text intValue];

        NSLog(@"Weight: %d", weight);
        NSLog(@"Reps: %d", reps);

        int nintyFiveInt = [self oneRepMax :0.95 :reps :weight];
        int nintyInt = [self oneRepMax :0.9 :reps :weight];
        int eightyFiveInt = [self oneRepMax :0.85 :reps :weight];
        int eightyInt = [self oneRepMax :0.8 :reps :weight];
        int seventyFiveInt = [self oneRepMax :0.75 :reps :weight];
        int seventyInt = [self oneRepMax :0.7 :reps :weight];
        int sixtyFiveInt = [self oneRepMax :0.65 :reps :weight];
        int sixtyInt = [self oneRepMax :0.6 :reps :weight];

        NSString *nintyFiveWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"95%%: %d lbs", nintyFiveInt];
        NSString *nintyWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"95%%: %d lbs", nintyInt];
        NSString *eightyFiveWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"95%%: %d lbs", eightyFiveInt];
        NSString *eightyWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"95%%: %d lbs", eightyInt];
        NSString *seventyFiveWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"95%%: %d lbs", seventyFiveInt];
        NSString *seventyWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"95%%: %d lbs", seventyInt];
        NSString *sixtyFiveWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"95%%: %d lbs", sixtyFiveInt];
        NSString *sixtyWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"95%%: %d lbs", sixtyInt];

        [self.nintyFiveResult setTitle:nintyFiveWeight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.nintyResult setTitle:nintyWeight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.eightyFiveResult setTitle:eightyFiveWeight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.eightyResult setTitle:eightyWeight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.seventyFiveResult setTitle:seventyFiveWeight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.seventyResult setTitle:seventyWeight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.sixtyFiveResult setTitle:sixtyFiveWeight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.sixtyResult setTitle:sixtyWeight forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    else{
        [self.nintyFiveResult setTitle:@"95%%: 0 lbs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.nintyResult setTitle:@"90%%: 0 lbs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.eightyFiveResult setTitle:@"85%%: 0 lbs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.eightyResult setTitle:@"80%%: 0 lbs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.seventyFiveResult setTitle:@"75%%: 0lbs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.seventyResult setTitle:@"70%%: 0 lbs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.sixtyFiveResult setTitle:@"65%%: 0 lbs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.sixtyResult setTitle:@"60%%: 0 lbs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

/* oneRepMax: This method is used to compute the one rep according to the values passed
   percent: represents the percentages displayed on the screen
   numReps: represents the number of reps in the reps field
   weightToLift: represents the number in the wieght field
   The method returns a float of the weight to be displayed on screen
 */
- (float)oneRepMax:(float) percent :(int) numReps :(int) weightToLift{

    float r = (float) numReps;
    float w = (float) weightToLift;
    float max = w*(1+(r/30));

    return percent*max;
}

/* printResults: This method is used to print the results of the weight on bar in thesecond UI View
   percent: represents the percentage of one rep max selected to put on the bar
   weightOnBar: represents the total weight to be computed into plates
   weightObject: used to compute the plate values
 */
- (void) printResults:(int) percent :(int) weightOnBar :(Weights*) weightObject{
    [self.resultTitle setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%: %d", percent, weightOnBar]];
    [self.weightObj setTotalWeight:weightOnBar];

    [self.fortyFivePlateLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test"]];
    [self.thirtyFivePlateLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"X %d", [self.weightObj getThirtyFives]]];
    [self.twentyFivePlateLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"X %d", [self.weightObj getTwentyFives]]];
    [self.tenPlateLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"X %d", [self.weightObj getTens]]];
    [self.fivePlateLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"X %d", [self.weightObj getFives]]];
    [self.twoFivePlateLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"X %d", [self.weightObj getTwoPointFives]]];
}

// Percentage Buttons

- (IBAction)clickNintyFive:(id)sender {
    int weight = [self.weightField.text intValue];
    int reps = [self.repsField.text intValue];
    int nintyFiveInt = [self oneRepMax :0.95 :reps :weight];
    [self printResults: 95: nintyFiveInt: _weightObj];
}

- (IBAction)clickNinty:(id)sender {
    int weight = [self.weightField.text intValue];
    int reps = [self.repsField.text intValue];
    int nintyFiveInt = [self oneRepMax :0.9 :reps :weight];
    [self printResults: 90: nintyFiveInt: _weightObj];
}

- (IBAction)clickEightyFive:(id)sender {
    int weight = [self.weightField.text intValue];
    int reps = [self.repsField.text intValue];
    int nintyFiveInt = [self oneRepMax :0.85 :reps :weight];
    [self printResults: 85: nintyFiveInt: _weightObj];
}

- (IBAction)clickEighty:(id)sender {
    int weight = [self.weightField.text intValue];
    int reps = [self.repsField.text intValue];
    int nintyFiveInt = [self oneRepMax :0.8 :reps :weight];
    [self printResults: 80: nintyFiveInt: _weightObj];
}

- (IBAction)clickSeventyFive:(id)sender {
    int weight = [self.weightField.text intValue];
    int reps = [self.repsField.text intValue];
    int nintyFiveInt = [self oneRepMax :0.75 :reps :weight];
    [self printResults: 75: nintyFiveInt: _weightObj];
}

- (IBAction)clickSeventy:(id)sender {
    int weight = [self.weightField.text intValue];
    int reps = [self.repsField.text intValue];
    int nintyFiveInt = [self oneRepMax :0.7 :reps :weight];
    [self printResults: 70: nintyFiveInt: _weightObj];
}

- (IBAction)clickSixtyFive:(id)sender {
    int weight = [self.weightField.text intValue];
    int reps = [self.repsField.text intValue];
    int nintyFiveInt = [self oneRepMax :0.65 :reps :weight];
    [self printResults: 65: nintyFiveInt: _weightObj];
}

- (IBAction)clickSixty:(id)sender {
    int weight = [self.weightField.text intValue];
    int reps = [self.repsField.text intValue];
    int nintyFiveInt = [self oneRepMax :0.6 :reps :weight];
    [self printResults: 60: nintyFiveInt: _weightObj];
}

@end
```

Comment: Picture of the workflow: http://i62.tinypic.com/bfhon8.jpg

Comment: Woah. Can you boil the code down to something more concise? Show only one label, not 7.

Comment: Added a smaller portion to directly address the question.

Comment: Is your `UILabel` your setting the text on even visible and not below some other subview?

Comment: I'm not sure if I created a subview by accident. (I don't know the first thing about trying to create one) The only thing that makes me think this might be a possible cause is that the buttons that cause me to navigate views use the modal segues. But I can click the back button I have on the second view to return to the original view.

Comment: First thing to check:  Are your outlet pointers set?  Odds are probably better than 50:50 they're nil, due to some sort of snafu with the NIB, et al.

Comment: How can I check if they are set to nil? Sorry I'm new to Objective-C and iOS Apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may not have connected the property to your UILabel.

Next to the line number of your `@property` declaration there is a little grey circle which should be filled. If it isn't, you need to control-drag your UILabel to the ViewController in the Interface Builder, then choose resultTitle as the outlet.

Comment: It is connected. Heres a image to show the connections of the elements in the view. http://i57.tinypic.com/2wd0djm.jpg

Comment: What if you try changing another property of the UILabel, e.g. `[self.fortyFivePlateLabel setHidden:TRUE];`?

Comment: If you are assigning the label you want to change to the property `resultTitle`, why are you then changing the text of `self.fortyFivePlateLabel` and not `self.resultTitle`?

Comment: I just tried to set the label to hidden and it also didn't work.

Comment: I am changing both because I would like both labels' text to change when navigating to the view.

Comment: What if you try to query some property of the label, e.g. NSLog(@"@",self.resultTitle.text); ?

Comment: Hmmm I'm actually getting null for before and after I edit the label. Any idea why?

Comment: Try the same command in the viewDidLoad method. If it's still null, I would double check the IB connection. I can't think of anything else that would cause this...

Comment: Does this happen for all text fields, or just the resultTitle?

Comment: I ended up figuring out a work around just now. It seems like I was making the calls to modify the labels too soon. It is still in the process of carrying out the action running the processes specified when clicking a percentage button that it has not yet began to load the next view I guess. I can just call it within viewDidLoad and it works fine now. Thanks for the debugging tips!